# Identification of SMD component marked HF package sc-75(sot-416)

Tags: identification, components, surface-mount

[image: SMD MARKING HF PACKAGE SOT-416]

Hi I really need to find this component but couldn't find the appropriate match in any smd code reference that also matches the package type.
The package is super small sc-75(sot-416).
Thanks